# How to set a Custom image programmatically to and UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a problem assigning a custom image to an UIBarButtonItem, the main problem is that the image appears as an white square when create the button.
here is my code:

```
fileprivate func configureNavigationBar() {
        tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = lot.name
        let exportImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "action.png")!
        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(showCreationView(_:)))
        let exportByEmail = UIBarButtonItem(image: exportImg, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(exportDataByEmail(_:)))
        tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [exportByEmail,addButton]
    }
```

The problem is with the **exportByEmail**, image is in the variable **exportImg** added from my assets:

[image: image1]

The result obtained from my code:
[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image's background must be transparent, and you can set always original rendering mode to image, to display without changes as following

```
let exportByEmail = UIBarButtonItem(image: exportImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(exportDataByEmail(_:)))
```